# Laptop battery critically low cannot remove notification

Tags: power-management, battery

I installed and used Linux for the first time - Ubuntu 18.04.01 LTS. My laptop's battery is almost dead sitting on 0% and the notification keeps popping every 5 minutes.

Is there any way to disable the notification?

- tried dconf editor' tweeks set critical on -5 level instead of 0  but didnt work. i have read every other question here and didnt solve my problem .
- also my latpop is a toshiba satelite p50-b which means battery cannot be unmounted

Here's a screenshot that might be useful:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get remove indicator-power
```

And reboot.

Answer (score -1):

Open **Settings** and the click on the left side on **Notification**.

[image]

Now you can ether set off **Lock Screen Notification** or search under **applications** for **Report a problem ...** and disable notifications.